# Can I create a Branch link and then immediately parse it for data without leaving the app?

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io

In my app, a user taps a button and generates a branch link. Elsewhere in the app, I want to provide them the ability to paste that link and then to parse that link for its data, do an appropriate API call to get more data and then show the user some additional screen.

Is this possible in Parse? All of the stuff I've seen before has to do with unpacking a Branch link in `didFinishLaunching` rather than any random view controller in the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The use case is possible using any of the two following methods:

1) Using the Branch SDK to parse the link and present the link data for routing. Docs: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#handle-links-in-your-own-app

2) Using Branch Link Read API to manually read the link and then display the link data in the app. Docs: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#link-read

Both the methods can be used to read/process the link to get the link data.

Please feel free to reach out us at integrations@branch.io in case of any further questions!